# Android app upgrade itself seems right but nothing happens

Tags: java, android, android-intent, upgrade, auto-update

I googled for an app upgrading itself from .apk file.
Here is code. But nothing happens. No error, just nothing. I tested on Android 12.

```
try {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://" + ApkFile_FullPath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(install);
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.i("aaaaa: ", "intent: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Is it even possible to upgrade itself?

Comment: First, that `Uri` is almost certainly wrong. Use `FileProvider` to serve up files that you can read via `content` `Uri` values. Second, `ACTION_VIEW` is no longer used for installs, as of API Level 29. You will need to look at using `PackageInstaller` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution to install an apk in 4 steps:**

1. Add these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml : [code](https://pastebin.com/irB3m4UX)
2. Add this inside the `<application>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml : [code](https://pastebin.com/Y1gbQhTJ)
3. Create a file named `file_paths.xml` in `xml` folder in `res` : [code](https://pastebin.com/jTBWfgE5)
4. Use this method to install an apk file. : [code](https://pastebin.com/z28Resi4)

Happy Coding!

Comment: I'm using pastebin because stackoverflow markdown was not working properly.